# Apply CSS Style for all elements except button

Tags: html, css

I have the following test code in my style.css (to turn borders on for all elements):

`* {
    border: 1px solid blue;     /*testing*/
}`

Currently, I am just changing 1px to 0px when I use this test feature.

`* {
    border: 0px solid blue;     /*testing*/
}`

But I found that buttons with borders, even `border=0`, do not take on default button style. So, I would like to exclude the button element from my test code. 
Something like this:

```
*:not([button]) {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

But the above doesn't work.

Is there a simple way to exclude  when applying a 1px border to all elements?

Comment: when value is zero you don't need to specify the unit cause zero is zero in any unit e.g. 0 millimetres = 0 miles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
*:not(button) {
  // ....
}
```

Square brackets are for attributes, as inside `:not()` you should have a selector.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly :) Says have to wait 10 mins to accept answer. I'll come back later to check accept